# Why the TCP Server does't receive any data from client in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I try to implement the `WiFi-Direct` and the `TCP server` in Android `phone-A`.

**The `phone-A` turn on the `WiFi-Direct` and connect with the `phone-B` , the `phone-A` also get the `Group Owner IP address`.**

**And I download the `Socket Protocol App` at `phone-B` as a `Client`. It connect to the `Group Owner IP address`.**

The `client` can receive the data from `Server` , but the `Server` can not receive the data from `Client`.

The code of the `Server` is like the following:

```
private static Socket socket;
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
public static final int PORT = 50006;

        public static class FileServerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Socket> {

                private Context context;
                private TextView statusText;
                private BufferedReader input_test;

                public FileServerAsyncTask(Context context, View statusText) {
                    this.context = context;
                    this.statusText = (TextView) statusText;
                }
                @Override
                protected Socket doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();

                        CommunicationThread comThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                        new Thread(comThread).start();

                        return socket;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(WifiP2P.TAG, e.getMessage());
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Socket socket) {

                }
            }


    public static final class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

            private Socket ClientSocket;
            private BufferedReader input;

            public CommunicationThread(Socket clientsocket){
                this.ClientSocket = clientsocket;
                Log.d(WifiP2P.TAG, "CommunicationThread , Client address is " + this.ClientSocket.getInetAddress());

            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    try {
                        Log.e(WifiP2P.TAG, "@@@@ while loop ");
                        this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.ClientSocket.getInputStream()));
                        String data = input.readLine();
                        Log.e(WifiP2P.TAG, "@@@@ Client Data = " + data);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The log stop at the `@@@@ while loop`.
The connection between `Server` and the `Client` is established. The `Server` can send the `Byte data` to Client.

But the `Server` can not receive the data from `Client`.

Did I missing something ?

Comment: You have a Port but where is the ip adress?

Comment: @BatuhanC The client know the IP address of Server. The connection between Server and the Client is established. The Server can send the Byte data to Client.
But the Server can not receive the data from Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you send a line feed from the client?

```
public String readLine()
                throws IOException
Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one 
of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage 
return followed immediately by a linefeed.
```

Comment: No , The Server didn't send a line feed to Client. Does it relate to the "Client send data to the Server" ? The Server can send the Byte data to Client , but the Server can not receive the data from Client.

Comment: Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if you are sending a line feed from the client to the server. Because the reader does not stop reading while the client doesn't send a line feed or a carriage return.

Comment: The client use Socket Protocol App to send the data. It seems no necessary to sending line feed by myself.

Comment: @Martin That doesn't make sense. If you're reading lines you need to send lines.

Comment: Sorry , I thought the App will add the lines automatic by it self. It work , Thanks a lot.